# Android image touch carousel

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-image

I have 5 semi-transparent images in my application. 
I need to select one of these images and apply it **OVER** another image (shown in background).
 
I would select these images moving horizontally (eg: touch left to right ), keeping the background visible. 
A sort of carousel, but I have to show one image at a time.

Any help in this regard would be very welcome.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it using gallery and image in FrameLayout to center it.
It works fine.